# Programmatically changing the selected tab of tabBarController without animation

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

There are two ways in accessing a view(assume view -4).

1. one way is directly on clicking a button in view -1.
2. other way is, on clicking a tableview cell in View -3.

So on clicking I want to load the view-3 without animation and directly display view-4. View-3 is the tabBar item with some index.

Summery: How to load a tabBar item without animation?

Answer (score 2):

you can try this code:

```
self.tabBarController.selectedIndex=index;
```

or

```
[self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:index];
```

set the index value according to your condition.

Comment: I used it but it will animate. I don't want it to be animated.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
//**If you are using tab bar controller**
[tabController setSelectedIndex:8];
[tabController setSelectedViewController:VC];

//**If you are using tab bar**
[tabBar setSelectedItem:(UITabBarItem * _Nullable)]
```